# Parenting mesh to armature. Why is part of the mesh not moving?

Tags: animation, mesh, armature, parent

I have modeled a very simple Lego figure with a tutorial from Udemy.
So far everything worked great, but now when I want to animate the character I have problems with parenting the armature to the mesh.
The parts of the mesh were modeled separately and then joined together.

[image: Hip not moving]

In the picture you can see the parented armature.
Here I rotated the root bone which should, as far as I understood, always move the whole mesh.
But as you can see the "hip" stays in it's original space.
The hip is also not influenced by any other bone movement.

Now I'm stuck with my progress in the course.
Hope anyone can help.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Check if the root bone has its "deform" option active, in the bones properties of the armature properties panel. If so, select all vertices of the hip, go to vertex tab, vertex groups, select (or create) a vertex group named "Root" and click assign button with a weight value of 1.0.

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot.  
One more question: When I'm in weight paint mode now and try to adjust the weight on the hips. I can only barely paint on the hips mesh to add some weight for bones. Is there a reason why that is so? I can paint anywhere else on the mesh but most of the hip part stays blue.

Comment: Another question:
Why do i have to put a weight on especially the hips with if every other part of the mesh rotates correctly without having to put a weight on it?